# Mapbox GL-JS - Why can't I display the directions dialog box?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I am wanting to add Mapbox directions to my map using [this Mapbox example from the documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-directions/) but the directions do not display. To be clear, this is what is not showing up :

[image]

My code is very simple, just taking directly from the example :

```
map.addControl(
new MapboxDirections({
accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
}),
'top-left'
);
```

Do I have a syntax error of some sort? I have tried adding the code in several different functions to make sure it is being executed, and the rest of my map works - my API key is good and my map is named "map", just as in the example. If this is not some syntax issue, I know I have had some z-index issues on my page. How would I access this element in CSS if that is the case? Perhaps it is hiding behind my map or something when called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MapboxDirections control requires the following to be included in the header - javascript and CSS :

```
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-directions/v4.0.2/mapbox-gl-directions.js"></script>
<link
rel="stylesheet"
href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-directions/v4.0.2/mapbox-gl-directions.css"
type="text/css"
/>
```